# XML transformation without custom namesapce tag using XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I have an scenario where I need to transform XML with custom namespace prefix but don't want to include that namespace in the result XML.

Original XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<order>
    <subject>
        <field name="firstname" id="10"><![CDATA[]]></field>
        <field name="middlename" id="27"/>
        <field name="lastname" id="13"><![CDATA[Singh]]></field>
        <field name="email" id="9"><![CDATA[]]></field>
        <field name="gender2" id="12"/>                
    </subject>   
</order>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://www.cubiksonline.com/CubiksOnline/WebServices/201207" xmlns:cub="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Cubiks.CubiksOnline.WebServices.DataContracts" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl xs fn cub soapenv ns">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <cub:ParticipantToRegister>
      <xsl:variable name="firstname" select="//*[local-name()='subject']/*[local-name()='field'][@*[local-name()='name']='firstname']"/>
      <xsl:variable name="lastname" select="//*[local-name()='subject']/*[local-name()='field'][@*[local-name()='name']='lastname']"/>
      <xsl:variable name="email" select="//*[local-name()='subject']/*[local-name()='field'][@*[local-name()='name']='email']"/>
      <cub:FirstName>
        <xsl:value-of select="$firstname"/>
      </cub:FirstName>
      <cub:LastName>
        <xsl:value-of select="$lastname"/>
      </cub:LastName>
      <cub:EmailAddress>
        <xsl:value-of select="$email"/>
      </cub:EmailAddress>
      <cub:IsAnonymous>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="(($firstname != '') and ($email != ''))">
            <xsl:text>false</xsl:text>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:text>true</xsl:text>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </cub:IsAnonymous>
      <cub:Gender>
        <xsl:value-of select="//*[local-name()='subject']/*[local-name()='field'][@*[local-name()='name']='gender2']"/>
      </cub:Gender>
      <cub:ExternalUserID>HRNX_Test</cub:ExternalUserID>
    </cub:ParticipantToRegister>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<cub:ParticipantToRegister xmlns:cub="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Cubiks.CubiksOnline.WebServices.DataContracts">
   <cub:FirstName />
   <cub:LastName>Singh</cub:LastName>
   <cub:EmailAddress />
   <cub:IsAnonymous>true</cub:IsAnonymous>
   <cub:Gender />
   <cub:ExternalUserID>HRNX_Test</cub:ExternalUserID>
</cub:ParticipantToRegister>
```

Expected Output:

```
<cub:ParticipantToRegister>
   <cub:FirstName />
   <cub:LastName>Singh</cub:LastName>
   <cub:EmailAddress />
   <cub:IsAnonymous>true</cub:IsAnonymous>
   <cub:Gender />
   <cub:ExternalUserID>HRNX_Test</cub:ExternalUserID>
</cub:ParticipantToRegister>
```

Please let me know whether this is possible, If yes what could be the soln for the same.

Comment: It's not possible. You **must** declare a namespace for your output document, and bind it to the `cub` prefix otherwise your XML isn't valid.

Comment: I know that xml won't be valid without namespace however for final result i.e for multiple "cub:ParticipantToRegister" I am going to insert it into main XML which contains all these namespace.

Comment: The actual problem is I have multiple "Original XML" and for each XML I want to create the inner XML which is as my expected XML, Concatenate all the result XML  and finally replace the concatenated result  XML in the main XML which contains all the namespace which leads to make whole XML valid so for this problem Is there any better solution or I could achieve this way?

Comment: OK, I understand what you would like to achieve. But is it  really an issue if the namespace is redeclared several times? In XML it shouldn't...